# my function always returns a huge number

Tags: c++, arrays

Now my function works better, but it did't return the minimum number, it returns the second largest... Could anyone help me? I can't find the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

void add_min(int*& a, int n){
    int c;
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
        if(a[i + 1] < a[i]){
            c = a[i + 1];
        }
        else{
            c = a[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout<< c <<std::endl;
    for(int s = 0; s < n; s++){
        a[s] += c;
    }
    for(int z = 0;z < n; z++){
            std::cout<< a[z] <<std::endl;
    }
 }


int main(){
    int n,i;
    std::cout<< "please enter the dimention of the array" <<std::endl;
    std::cin>> n;
    int *arr = new int[n-1];
    std::cout<< "please enter the integers in the array" <<std::endl;
    for(i = 0;i < n; i++){
            std::cin>>arr[i];
    }
    add_min(arr, n);
    delete [] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the least of this program's problems. I'd start with not passing the array and using an uninitialized one.

Comment: Yeah, there's more wrong than right with this one.

Comment: Technically you don't have a valid C++ program, as C++ (as of C++11) doesn't have [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). So the declaration `int a[n]` in `add_min` is not technically a valid declaration.

Comment: I didn't even know that `int a[n]` would compile :o

Comment: @user1520427 It's an extension in some compilers.

Answer (score 1):

These huge numbers you are talking about are the definition of *undefined output*. Why are you getting this?

In your loop, you're doing:

```
if(a[i + 1] < a[i])
```

But remember that arrays are *zero-based* in C++, so you're getting out of bounds in the last iteration, because `i + 1` will be `n`, and the array's size is *n-1* (Indexes run in the range [0, n-1]).

Tip: Debugging your code can save your time (and your life), use the debugger!

Furthermore, more important issue, you're using an *uninitialized* array that initially contains garbage values.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1 :

```
int c, a[n];
b = a[n];
```

size of a = n , therefore you can at maximum access `a[n-1]` , not `a[n]` since index starts `from 0` , not 1 in `c` .

Problem 2 :

> have you initialized the values of array `a` ?

when arrays are initialized in functions , they are filled with `random` values .

Answer (score 1):

Besides the problem mentioned in my comment, the problem is that you're using an uninitialized local array, which means it will contain seemingly random data. You also start out by reading a value *out of bounds*  with `b = a[n];`

I think what you really meant to do was to pass in the complete array as an argument, instead of creating new in the function.

Comment: Yes, but because I have to call the array by reference, I can't use int& a[]

Comment: @JuneWitt You can still pass the array as a pointer, and modify the contents of it.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked, but there is a new problem...I edit it, could you please help?